# Navbar widget with search autocomplete option Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create reusable global navigation header widget with angularjs which has search input field which prompts autocomplete widget.

What is the best method to approach so that i can include this module in other angular app.

If there is a good documentation on how to create custom modules,  that would be much helpful

Comment: `custom modules` typically means `directives` within angular. Very powerful tools

Answer (score 1):

The [UI Directives for Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) library has a Typeahead function which is perfect for this, I can post a code sample if you wish but the documentation is pretty self explanatory